# how to reverse the last and first word in a string using regex java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this string...

"My Phone number is out of range. This is Mark"

I want to reform this as ...

"Mark Phone number is out of range. This is My"

How to do it with regex in JAVA ?

what  I have tried so far

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "My Phone number is out of range. This is Mark";
    str=str.replaceAll("^(\\w+)(.*)(\\w+)$","$3$2$1");
    System.out.print(str);
    }
```

**output:**

```
ky Phone number is out of range. This is MarMy
```

Answer (score 0):

split will be easy..

```
 split() the string based on \\s+ and put it in String array arr
 Do temp = arr[0] ; 
arr[0] = arr[arr.length-1]; 
arr[arr.length-1] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @TheLostMind split will be easier and cleaner to use but if you want to do it using regular expressions then here you go.

You are using \w+ to match a word at the end but it will match only one character at the end. In order to match to the whole word you need to match the space just before the last word. You can use below expression to do that.

```
str=str.replaceAll("^(\\w+)(.*)([ ]+)(\\w+)$","$4$3$2$3$1");
```

here $3 is the matched space character.

Hope this helps.